# ¿Cómo insertar String en un Array de objetos?

Tags: android, alertdialog

Buenas tardes.

Tengo un `Alertdialog Multochoice` que se llena a partir de un array de objetos. Estos datos, los obtengo desde un `WebServices`. Lo que ahora necesito hacer, es insertar un string a la fuerza para que me muestre una opción que diga "TODOS", solo que eso nunca lo he hecho.

Les dejo mi código:

```
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList arrayList){
        super.onPostExecute(arrayList);

        final String[] zona = new String[ZonaArrayList.size()];
        // zona = ZonaArrayList.toArray(zona);
        for(int i=0; i<ZonaArrayList.size(); i++){
            //Obtiene el campo Descripción y lo agrega al array de strings "zona".
            zona[i] = ZonaArrayList.get(i).getDescripcion();
        }

        AlertDialog.Builder dialog=new AlertDialog.Builder(Clientes.this);

        dialog.setTitle("Selecciona la(s) Zonas a Visitar");
        final boolean[] selZona={false,false,false};
        dialog.setMultiChoiceItems(zona,selZona,new DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1, boolean arg2) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("ONC_Settings", 0);
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
                editor.putInt("Zona",ZonaArrayList.get(0).getId());
                editor.commit();
                if(arg2) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Zona Seleccionada " + zona[arg1],Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
            }
        });

        dialog.setPositiveButton("Ok",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                //Mandar a llamar metodo Clientes con el filtro
                SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("ONC_Settings", 0);
                AsynClien task = new AsynClien(settings.getString("ONControlWSURL", "").toString(),settings.getInt("Zona",1),settings.getString("ONControlToken", "").toString(),settings.getInt("ONControlEmpresa",1));
                //Call execute
                task.execute();
            }
        });

        dialog.setNegativeButton("Cancelar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.cancel();
            }
        });

        AlertDialog alertDialog=dialog.create();
        alertDialog.show();
    }
```

Aqui es donde necesito insertar ese string afuerzas

Error

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                  Process: mx.com.oncontrol.oncontrolmovile, PID: 31902
                                                                                  java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=3; index=3
                                                                                      at mx.com.oncontrol.oncontrolmovile.Clientes$AsyncZona.onPostExecute(Clientes.java:305)
                                                                                      at mx.com.oncontrol.oncontrolmovile.Clientes$AsyncZona.onPostExecute(Clientes.java:262)
                                                                                      at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:632)
                                                                                      at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
                                                                                      at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:645)
                                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
                                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
                                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
                                                                                      at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 1):

Por lo que veo zona es el array que contiene los items que se van a mostrar en el AlertDialog.
Este array es un array de String y es creado y populado en esta parte:

```
final String[] zona = new String[ZonaArrayList.size()];
// zona = ZonaArrayList.toArray(zona);
for(int i=0; i<ZonaArrayList.size(); i++){
    //Obtiene el campo Descripción y lo agrega al array de strings "zona".
    zona[i] = ZonaArrayList.get(i).getDescripcion();

}
```

Tendrías que agregar un item mas al final, pero para eso el array tendría que ser mas grande, yo lo haria asi:

```
int size = ZonaArrayList.size() + 1; // Uno extra para colocar el item TODOS
final String[] zona = new String[size];
// zona = ZonaArrayList.toArray(zona);
for(int i=0; i<size; i++){
    //Obtiene el campo Descripción y lo agrega al array de strings "zona".
    zona[i] = ZonaArrayList.get(i).getDescripcion();

}
zona[size - 1] = "TODOS"; // Se le resta 1 porque los indices de los arrays inician en 0
```

Es de notar que en el `for` ya no se esta comparando `i` contra `ZonaArrayList.size()` sino contra `size`.

Comment: amigo me manda error, te adjunto el error

Comment: Tienes un `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`, eso quiere decir que estas leyendo o escribiendo afuera del tamaño del array. Recuerda crear el array de `String` con un espacio extra para el `String` `"TODOS"` es decir, crealo con tamaño `ZonaArrayList.size() + 1`

Comment: te adjunto mi codigo de como lo tengo me sigue marcando el mismo error

Comment: Emm, ¿Donde lo adjuntaste?

Answer (score 1):

Esta es la forma estándar de transformar un ArrayList a un Array:

```
List<String> list = ..;
String[] array = list.toArray(new String[0]); 
// .toArray(..) recibe el tipo de dato del array 
// que transformará; si lo dejases sin parámetro, 
// retornaría un Object[]
```

De esta forma te evitas tener que poner en tu código una iteración de copiado y lo haces más legible a futuro (no está mal hacer el for para copiar, solo que siempre es mejor utilizar los métodos que te entrega el lenguaje, para hacer lo más simple y conciso tu código).

Y ya que necesitas agregar un nuevo elemento, lo que haría es:

```
ZonaArrayList.add('TODOS', 0); //Agrego en la posición inicial la nueva opción
String[] zonas = ZonaArrayList.toArray(new String[0]);
```

y ya está :)